# Windows 7 Action Center

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, backup

I would appreciate it if someone can guide me to the new MS APIs necessary for modifying/controlling the Windows 7 Action Center. What I need to do is integrate the Backup notification messages in my application which is a backup application in the Action Center. In other words, I want Windows to show that the backup operation was successful after the third-party software completes its backup operation.

To be even more specific.... is there a way to treat backup notifications the same way as the security notification/status messages... for example after installing an Anti Virus application... Virus Protection field in action center shows a message similar to this one:

```
<App Name> reports that it is up to date and virus scanning is on.
```

Where `<App Name>` is the third-party application name.

Is there a way to do something similar to that but on the Backup section of Action Center??.

Comment: Please don't post exact duplicates of your questions.  If you still need an answer, edit this question with any additional information you've found since it was asked and it will be bumped to the front page.

Comment: Sorry man but I felt like my question has somewhat died and needed to be refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that Microsoft have some sort of hidden APIs that are only given on a Non Disclosure Agreement (NDA) and those have to be requested from wscisv@microsoft.com.

This seems to be the only method available to register an Anti Virus or a Firewall application in Windows Security Center. Still I haven't found any hints if there are any APIs that MS is keeping for themselves for security reasons to enable the registration of a backup application in WAC (Windows Action Center) or if the application registration is even possible.

Still waiting for a reply from MS to clear the matter.

Comment: Turns out..  communicating status with action center is not available for backup products...

What a shame :(

Answer (score 1):

Applications can communicate status through registry keys for backup purposes. See MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891959(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thx for the reply man.... I've already seen those keys and I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is actually among them, since there is no specific key that can be used in setting backup status as complete.

Comment: Actually for Backup purposes it is impossible to communicate status. But only control Windows Backup through Registry Keys.